# Script load two arguments

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, perl, variable

I have perl script which need two arguments, for example:

```
./PerlScript 0001 192.168.100.200
```

But I need run this script more time (40x).

```
./PerlScript 0003 192.168.100.202
./PerlScript 0061 192.168.100.205
./PerlScript 0061 192.168.100.206
...
...
...
```

I need insert arguments automaticly after PerlScript and how to do it?
Load from file or create array?

Comment: Depends... if there's a system, create them with a script. If there isn't, you probably need them listed in a file or such, and then you can just read the file and run the scripts...

Comment: Are you running PearlScript from another perl script, or from, for example, bash?

Answer (score 1):

let's say your list of arguments are in a "thelist" file as so:

```
0001 192.168.100.200
0003 192.168.100.202
0061 192.168.100.205
0061 192.168.100.206
```

You could:

```
printf "./PerlScript %s %s\n" $(cat thelist) | bash
```

Note that if you do this (as in your exemple) : they are run sequentially.

change to

```
printf "./PerlScript %s %s & \n" $(cat thelist) | bash
```

to have them launched each in the background (but beware not to put your machine on its knees...)

Comment: `< thelist xargs -n 2 ./perl_script`

Comment: @RakeshSharma: you could add yours as a separate answer, as it does also cover the OP's needs and provide another way to do it. each has its own merits (printf allows a lot of flexibility, such as providing a way to add the `&` to each ones, but yours is quite efficient and close to the OP's need)

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to do this, if the arguments are stored in a file, is to use `xargs`.

The `xargs` utility runs another program with arguments read from its standard input.

With

```
xargs -n 2 ./PerlScript <list.in
```

`xargs` would run `./PerlScript` with two argument at a time (`-n 2`) with the arguments taken from the file `list.in` in the current directory.

The file `list.in` could be either

```
0001 192.168.100.200
0003 192.168.100.202
0061 192.168.100.205
0061 192.168.100.206
```

or

```
0001
192.168.100.200
0003
192.168.100.202
0061
192.168.100.205
0061
192.168.100.206
```

`xargs` can also read the arguments from a pipe:

```
somecommand | xargs -n 2 ./PerlScript
```

Here, `somecommand` is some command that generates output in the same form as the `list.in` used in the previous example.